# Unable to spy on function using Jasmine inside a jQuery on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, karma-jasmine

The following is in foo.js

```
var analytics = {};

analytics.myLinks = function(){
    return 2;
};

analytics.myView = function() {
    analytics.myLinks();
};

$('#marquee').on('click', analytics.myView);
```

The following is my spec file foo.spec.js Fixture is appended using jasmine-fixture utility's affix helper. (https://github.com/searls/jasmine-fixture)

```
(function() {
    describe('click event handlers', function() {

        it('calls function when #marquee is clicked on', function() {
            affix('#marquee');
            spyOn(analytics, 'myView').and.callThrough();
            $('#marquee').trigger('click');
            expect(analytics.myView).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });

        it('calls inner function when #marquee is clicked on', function() {
            affix('#marquee');
            spyOn(analytics, 'myLinks').and.callThrough();
            $('#marquee').trigger('click');
            expect(analytics.myLinks).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });

}).call(this);
```

I am using Karma as my test runner and it throws an error on the above unit test saying 
*"Expected spy myView to have been called."*
and 
*"Expected spy myLinks to have been called."*

I have tried different variations of the same but not sure where I am going wrong. Please help!

Comment: Does the other test pass?

Comment: @Nix, both of the unit tests shown here don't pass. Other tests within the codebase pass, writing off the possibility that something might not  be configured right.

Comment: UPDATE: If I add this line AFTER the spyOn in each of the tests, the tests pass:
    $('#marquee').on('click', analytics.myView);

What can I infer from this?

Comment: Presumably your `foo.js` code runs **before** your tests are executed so there is no `#marquee` element to bind a click event handler to. You could change your `foo.js` to use event delegation but that might not be exactly what you want to do ~ `$(document).on('click', '#marquee', analytics.myView)`